# How to get HTML Form elements as JSON object when submit?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have an HTML form [(screenshot of the HTML form)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0x38x.png)

When I hit submit I am getting input elements values using

```
var input = $(this).serializeArray();
```

Obviously it is going to return it as an array.

If I want to return each row of the form as a JSON object, then array of these objects, Whats the best way to do it ?

```
  {
      "row": {
        "dimension": "Sales",
        "levels": {
          "level1": "NorthEast",
          "level2": "East",
          "level3": "MidWest"
        }
      }
    }
```

Any leads/direction are well appreciated ? (attached the code snippet below, line 56, 57 in javascript)

```js
function Row(dimension, levels) {
  this.dimension = dimension;
  this.levels = levels;
}

class Coordinate {
  constructor(x, y) {
    this.x = x;
    this.y = y;
  }
}

$(document).ready(function(e) {
  var maxrows = 6;
  var rows = 1;
  var i = 1;
  var j = 1;
  var maxlevels = 2;
  $(".add_more").click(function(e) {
    if (rows <= maxrows) {
      var dimension_name = "dimension" + i;
      var level_name1 = "level" + i + "_" + 1;
      var level_name2 = "level" + i + "_" + 2;
      var level_name3 = "level" + i + "_" + 3;
      var html =
        '<div class="form-group row"><div class="col-xs-2"><input type="text" class="form-control" value="sales" name="' +
        dimension_name +
        '"></div> <div class="col-xs-2"><input type="text" class="form-control" value="Northeast" name="' +
        level_name1 +
        '"></div> <div class="col-xs-2"><input type="text" class="form-control" value="NorthWest" name="' +
        level_name2 +
        '"></div> <div class="col-xs-2"> <input type="text" class="form-control" value="WestCoast" name="' +
        level_name3 +
        '"></div> <div id="del" class="col-xs-2"> <input type="button" value="X"><br></div> </div></div>';
      $("#inputContainer").append(html);
      rows++;
      i++;
    }
  });

  $("#inputContainer").on("click", "#del", function(e) {
    $(this)
      .parent("div")
      .remove();
    rows--;
    $("#svgContainer").text("");
    console.log("removed");
  });

  $("form").submit(function(e) {
    event.preventDefault();
    $("#svgContainer").text("");
    var dim = [];
    var lev = [];
    //
    var input = $(this).serializeArray();
    console.log(input);
    var inputLength = input.length;
    for (var i = 0; i < inputLength; i++) {
      var val = input[i].name.startsWith("dim");
      if (val) {
        dim.push(input[i].value);
      } else {
        lev.push(input[i].value);
      }
    }
    drawSpider(dim, lev);
  });

  function drawCircle(originX, originY, r) {
    var cx = originX;
    var cy = originY;
    var circle =
      '<circle cx="' +
      cx +
      '" cy="' +
      cy +
      '" r="' +
      r +
      '" style="stroke:#000000; fill:white" />';
    var existing = $("#svgContainer").html();
    $("#svgContainer").html(existing + circle);
  }

  function drawSpider(dim, lev) {
    var spiderContainer = $("#spiderContainer");
    var width = spiderContainer.width();
    var height = spiderContainer.height();
    var originX = width / 2;
    var originY = height / 2;
    drawCircle(originX, originY, 60);
    writeText(originX, originY);
    var thetaIncrement = (2 * Math.PI * (180 / Math.PI)) / dim.length;
    var theta = 0;
    for (var i = 0; i < dim.length; i++) {
      var radius = 60;
      var cosTheta = Math.cos(theta * (Math.PI / 180));
      var sinTheta = Math.sin(theta * (Math.PI / 180));
      var x1 = originX + radius * cosTheta;
      var y1 = originY + radius * sinTheta;
      var limblength = 300;
      var x2 = x1 + limblength * Math.cos(theta * (Math.PI / 180));
      var y2 = y1 + limblength * Math.sin(theta * (Math.PI / 180));
      drawLine(x1, y1, x2, y2);
      var pointsBetween = getPointsBetween(x1, y1, x2, y2, 3);
      for (var j = 0; j < 3; j++) {
        var spotRadius = 10;
        var x =
          (pointsBetween[j].x -
            spotRadius +
            (pointsBetween[j].x + spotRadius)) /
          2;
        var y =
          (pointsBetween[j].y +
            spotRadius +
            (pointsBetween[j].y - spotRadius)) /
          2;
        drawCircle(x, y, spotRadius);
        writeText(x + 15, y - 10);
      }

      theta += thetaIncrement;
    }
  }

  function writeText(x, y) {
    // x = x + 15;
    // y = y - 10;
    var txt = '<text  x="' + x + '" y="' + y + '" style="">Test</text>';
    var existing = $("#svgContainer").html();
    $("#svgContainer").html(existing + txt);
  }

  var spotCount;
  function getPointsBetween(x1, y1, x2, y2, spotCount) {
    var pointsBetween = [];
    x2 = Math.ceil(x2);
    if (x1 != x2) {
      //Calculating slope
      var m = (y2 - y1) / (x2 - x1);
      var b = y1 - m * x1;
      var deltaX = (x2 - x1) / spotCount;
      for (var k = 1; k <= spotCount; k++) {
        var point = new Coordinate();
        point.x = x1 + deltaX * k;
        point.y = m * point.x + b;
        pointsBetween.push(point);
      }
    } else {
      var deltaY = (y2 - y1) / spotCount;
      for (var k = 1; k <= spotCount; k++) {
        var point = new Coordinate();
        point.x = x1;
        point.y = y1 + deltaY * k;
        pointsBetween.push(point);
      }
    }
    return pointsBetween;
  }

  function drawLine(x1, y1, x2, y2) {
    var line =
      '<line  x1="' +
      x1 +
      '" y1="' +
      y1 +
      '" x2="' +
      x2 +
      '" y2="' +
      y2 +
      '" style="stroke: black; stroke-width:2;"/>';
    var existing = $("#svgContainer").html();
    $("#svgContainer").html(existing + line);
  }
});
```

```css
#spiderContainer{
    border-style: solid;
    width: 1000px;
    height: 1000px;
  }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
     <head>
            <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="custom.css">
            <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
            <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
            <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    </head>
<body>
<div class="container-fluid">
<p>Spider</p>

<form>
    <div id="inputContainer"> 
            <div class="form-group row">
        <!-- <div id="inputContainer"> -->
            <div class="col-xs-2"> Dimension <input type="text" class="form-control" value ="testdimension" name="dimension0" id="dimension"> </div>
            <div class="col-xs-2"> Level 1 <input type="text" class="form-control" value ="testlevel1" name="level0_1" id="level1"></div>
            <div class="col-xs-2"> Level 2 <input type="text" class="form-control" value ="testlevel2" name="level0_2" id="level2"> </div>
            <div class="col-xs-2"> Level 3 <input type="text" class="form-control" value ="testlevel3"  name="level0_3" id="level2"></div>
            <div class="col-xs-2">  Add  <input type="button" class="form-control add_more btn btn-primary"  value="+"></div><br><br><br>
        <!-- </div> -->
            </div>
    </div>
    <input class="btn btn-primary" type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>

    <div class="row justify-content-md-center" id="spiderContainer">
        <div class="col">
            <svg id="svgContainer" viewBox="0 0 1000 1000">
            </svg>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="formlogic.js"></script>
</html>
```

Comment: Did you try `$("form").serialize();`

Comment: Just a note on that possible duplicate: the question is quite old and jquery (now at least, if not even then) has methods to re-parse the JSON returned from .serialize() without needing another 3rd party library.

Comment: Hi Azim, you might like to have a read of [mcve] - you've included a *lot* of code here, that most likely isn't relevant to the actual issue.

Comment: @freedomn-m serilaize() is returning an array